# "I'm more against it than for it."

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence fine?

> He gave his opinion on this issue. I’m more against it than for it.

Or what else can I say expressing the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm more for it than against it" sounds a lot better to me than the opposite. The most succinct way to say the same thing might just be simply:

> He gave his opinion on this issue. I'm inclined to disagree with it.

(or "with him").

It conveys both that you don't agree, but also that it's not a 100% disagreement, and flows more smoothly than your example.

Comment: Yes, I too think this is a better version.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the antecedent is clear, there is no harm in substituting a pronoun for a subject. In this case it is clear that *it* refers to "his opinion" on the matter. So, yes, it's fine as it stands.

Comment: I interpreted "it" as referring to the issue, but in a real context I think it would be unambiguous.

Comment: I don't agree. I would not normally use "for" referring to an opinion, so I would interpret this as referring to the issue, not to his opinion; and until I read your answer it never occurred to me that there was any ambiguity in this.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I think the ambiguity lies in the He / I contrast. If the statement were "I gave my opinion on this issue. I'm more against it than for it," I would say *it* definitely referred to *issue*. But *he* is the subject of the first sentence and *opinion* is the object, which marks it for me as the central point of reference to which a pronoun might refer.

Answer (score 1):

You could say things like:

> On the whole, I feel that the bad outweighs the good.
>
> While the proposal has some interesting points, it also has problems that prevent me from endorsing it in its current form.
>
> Certain things will need to be addressed before we can move forward with it.
>
> There are more things that I don't like about it than things that I do like.
>
> I think it will do more harm than good.

Comment: please read Orwell's [essay on the decline of English](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/acad/intrel/orwell46.htm), then don't make such long sentences when a shorter one conveys just as much information! =P (especially the 2nd one...)